# Vi keybindings for R command line like in Bash

Tags: bash, r, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

#### Context

I like editing and manipulating the bash command line using vi-style key bindings with the following setting:

```
set -o vi
```

However, when I start R on the command-line, these keybindings disappear.
I know that the [Vim-R plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628) allows for Vim keybindings when you run R through the Conque Shell, but I'm not entirely happy with that experience, and, regardless, sometimes I just want to run R on the standard command-line.

#### Question

- Is there any way of getting Vi style key bindings in R on the command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you to Joshua Ulrich and progo's answers, which helped to get me started.

Below I record my experience:

#### Initial setup

I tried `set keymap vi` and `set editing-mode vi`. When I started R in my Gnome Terminal, some shortcuts worked and others did not.
In particular `cc`, and `dd` (i.e., delete lines) did not work at all, and `cw` and `dw`  performed the action of deleting words but did not update the display until I pressed an additional key, which is not a functional experience.

#### Replacing missing functionality

- I found this [inputrc](http://haller.ws/projects/bash/inputrc) file that gave me a few ideas.
- [The help page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readline+3) was helpful, naturally.

I added the following to `~/.inputrc`, which fixed the obvious problems mentioned above:

```
set completion-ignore-case on

set editing-mode vi

$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-insert
    "\C-l": clear-screen
    "\C-p": history-search-backward
    "\C-n": history-search-forward
    # alt dot cycles through last argument
    "\e.":yank-last-arg

    set keymap vi-command
    "D":kill-line
    "dw": kill-word
    "dd": kill-whole-line
    "db": backward-kill-word
    "cc": "ddi"
    "cw": "dwi"
    "cb": "dbi"
    "diw": "lbdw"
    "yiw": "lbyw"
    "ciw": "lbcw"
    "diW": "lBdW"
    "yiW": "lByW"
    "ciW": "lBcW"
    "gg": beginning-of-history
    "G": end-of-history
$endif
```

Answer (score 13):

Add this to your `.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Answer (score 7):

The R commandline seems to use Readline. Readline uses `.inputrc` for settings:

```
set keymap vi
```

to your `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: R seems to read ~/.inputrc each time R is invoked.