# Are these two vi-related `.inputrc` lines redundant?

Tags: bash, vi

I've seen people recommend putting both of the following lines in one's `.inputrc` to enable vi key-mappings:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

Sometimes, they are recommended [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235034/vi-keybindings-for-r-command-line-like-in-bash); sometimes, they are recommended [together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/is-it-possible-to-have-vim-key-bindings-in-terminal). Gah! Are both necessary on any systems?

---

As a greedy side note, if either of those are included in one's `.inputrc`, is it still necessary to include:

```
set -o vi
```

...in one's `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the first line is necessary:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

The second line defines how future manual key mappings will be applied:

```
set keymap vi
```

Answer (score 4):

The file `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` controls the library [`readline`](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/). Readline is used by many many programs (including bash).

The second one, `set -o vi` controls only bash. `vimrc` has no effect on bash.

Comment: Oops!! Including `.vimrc` was a typo. I meant `.inputrc`! Thank you! And I realize that `.inputrc` controls readline; I'm trying to ask whether those two it is necessary to include both lines in that file.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy If you have that in your inputrc it's unnecessary to use `set -o vi`

Comment: I'm being terribly confusing. I'm wondering whether it's necessary to include *both* `set editing-mode vi` and `set keymap vi` in my `.inputrc`.